# how to detect encoding of uploaded csv file

Tags: php, linux, bash, csv, character-encoding

I`ve have **data.csv** file, that must be uploaded to server , parsed ....

This file can have different encodings. I must detect it and convert to utf8.

At this moment **php** function  **mb_detect_encoding** always return utf8.
i tryed:

```
<?php 
mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents($_FILES["csv_uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]));
```

or

```
<?php 
mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents($saved_file_path));
```

mb_detect_encoding returns utf8.

if i use bash command

```
$ file -bi csv_import_1378376486.csv |awk -F "=" '{print $2}'
```

it rerurns iso-8859-1

so when i try

```
iconv --from-code=iso-8859-1 --to-code=utf-8 csv_import_1378382527.csv
```

it is not readable.

**The real encoding is  cp1251, by i cann`t detect it.**
Can anyone help me to solve  this problem?

Comment: This is an inherent problem of text encodings. You can't always detect them correctly, you can only guess them most of the time. Unless there is some meta information available.

Answer (score 10):

As someone noticed in the PHP docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php):

> If you try to use mb_detect_encoding() to detect whether a string is
>   valid UTF-8, use the strict mode, it is pretty worthless otherwise.

So you should try using the `true` param when detecting encoding:

```
mb_detect_encoding($str, mb_detect_order(), TRUE);
```

If you can predict some possible encodings, you can list them instead of using  [`mb_detect_order()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-order.php).

Comment: mb_detect_encoding does not really work as you would expect.
It appears the function only checks for the first character and the rest is forgotten which creates a problem because say you have a document that has a non-utf-8 char at line 500; it'll be malformed or have missing data when importing from UTF-8.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72933

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot ! If someone comes up years later on this post, there is a bug with the mb_detect_encoding (check Jame's link above), apply one of the solution below if only a single encoding is given:
1. Repeating UTF-8 achieves the expected result, e.g. mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8, UTF-8')
2. When you specify single encoding, the proper function for this task is "mb_check_encoding()" rather than "mb_detect_encoding()".
3. Or use `mb_detect_order()` in the param of `mb_detec_encoding` function.
=> I use option 3 (ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 input files) and this does the job !